# How to join two strings as two strings seperated for a SQL command in Python?

Tags: python, sql-server, string

Probably, my question sounds strange!
However, I need this SQL query in Python:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT TABLE_NAME AS TABLE FROM M_CS_TABLES WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'TEST' ")
```

Since 'TEST' schema changes I need a query like that:

```
schema_name = 'TEST'
cursor.execute(" SELECT TABLE_NAME AS TABLE FROM M_CS_TABLES WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = " + str(schema_name))
```

But the output of this line will be:

' SELECT TABLE_NAME AS TABLE FROM M_CS_TABLES WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = TEST'

Not:

" SELECT TABLE_NAME AS TABLE FROM M_CS_TABLES WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'TEST' "

What is needed.

I would be appreciated for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap `'TEST'` in another pair of quotes, i.e. use `'"TEST"'`.

Better yet, insert `'TEST'` by using `str.format`.

```
>>> schema_name = 'TEST'
>>> 'blablabla "{}"'.format(schema_name)
'blablabla "TEST"'
```

Comment: I just add it to your answer: >>> schema_name = 'TEST' >>> "blablabla '%s' " %schema_name , it has also the same output: "blablabla 'TEST' "

Answer (score 2):

this is rather basic SQL practice. NEVER concatenate the string like that.

for your case the best way to do it is just:

```
schema_name = 'TEST'
cursor.execute("SELECT TABLE_NAME AS TABLE FROM M_CS_TABLES WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = %s", schema_name)
```

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Comment: This answer is better than mine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I receive this error: hdbcli.dbapi.ProgrammingError: (0, 'Invalid parameters : execute(SELECT TABLE_NAME AS TABLE FROM M_CS_TABLES WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = %s, TEST, {})')

Comment: @Vahid which library are you using? for different libraries sometimes they use different placeholders. so instead of %s, it might be ? or {}.

Comment: @fahyikyong Regardless of library, When I run this code in Python 3.6: >> schema_name = 'TEST', >> "SELECT TABLE_NAME AS TABLE FROM M_CS_TABLES WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = %s", schema_name, output is: ('SELECT TABLE_NAME AS TABLE FROM M_CS_TABLES WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = %s', 'TEST')

Comment: But when I run this one: >> schema_name = " 'TEST' ", >> "SELECT TABLE_NAME AS TABLE FROM M_CS_TABLES WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = {} ".format(schema_name), output is: "SELECT TABLE_NAME AS TABLE FROM M_CS_TABLES WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = 'TEST' "

Comment: Yes @Vahid. That's the correct way of doing, it will not print out the full SQL query that you want. Read the link i pasted in the answer, and also google up SQL injection attacks.